# Required Mime Type for CSV

Tags: jsp, csv

Is there some way to get proper mime type for .csv files to include in the attachment of my jsp page?

Answer (score 4):

At the top of your JSP:

```
<% response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv"); %>
```

Comment: It should be <% response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv"); %>, because setHeader only takes two parameters, not as one.

Answer (score 2):

```
Content-Type: text/csv
```